# RSForm!Pro Update form class if the error message shown

Tags: jquery, rsform

What's the best way to update the form class in RSForm!Pro if the error message is shown?

Could this be done using jQuery or a PHP script?

The code when the error is shown is:

```
<form action="http://webaddresshere.com" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="formResponsive" id="userForm" method="post"><p class="error">Please complete all required fields!</p>
<h2>Inapub in your inbox</h2>
<!-- Do not remove this ID, it is used to identify the page so that the pagination script can work correctly -->
<fieldset id="rsform_5_page_0" class="formHorizontal formContainer">
    <div class="rsform-block rsform-block-intro">
        <p>Subscribe to our newsletter today to recieve the latest blogs and stories from the team and exclusive product offers</p>
    </div>
    <div class="rsform-block rsform-block-full-name">
        <div class="formBody"><input type="text" class="rsform-input-box" onfocus="this.value=''" id="Full name" name="form[Full name]" size="20" value="Full name"><span class="formValidation"><span class="formNoError" id="component47">Please enter your full name</span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rsform-block rsform-block-email-address">
        <div class="formBody"><input type="text" class="rsform-input-box rsform-error" onfocus="this.value=''" id="email address" name="form[email address]" size="20" value="email address"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rsform-block rsform-block-pubsupplier">
        <div class="formBody"><input type="checkbox" id="PubSupplier0" value="I work in a pub" name="form[PubSupplier][]"><label for="PubSupplier0">I work in a pub</label><input type="checkbox" id="PubSupplier1" value="I am a supplier" name="form[PubSupplier][]"><label for="PubSupplier1">I am a supplier</label></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rsform-block rsform-block-over-18">
        <div class="formBody"><input type="checkbox" id="Over 180" value="I confirm I'm over 18" name="form[Over 18][]"><label for="Over 180">I confirm I'm over 18</label></div>
    </div>
    <span class="formValidation"><span class="formError" id="component48">Please enter a valid email address</span></span>
<span class="formValidation"><span class="formError" id="component49">Please state you profession</span></span>
<span class="formValidation"><span class="formError" id="component50">Please confirm you are over 18.</span></span>
    <div class="rsform-block rsform-block-subscribe">
        <div class="formBody"><input type="submit" class="rsform-submit-button" id="Subscribe" name="form[Subscribe]" value="Subscribe"><span class="formValidation"></span></div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<input type="hidden" value="5" name="form[formId]"></form>
```

When the error Please complete all required fields!

is shown I want the form class to be updated (or at least a class appended to it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how RSForm!Pro shows an errors message, but I assume there is a pre-defined HTML element with a class that is set to `display: block` if there is an error.

So what I would suggest doing is, make the error appear, then inspect the error element and check for any classes, then you can use the following jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var errorMsg = $('.formError');

    if( errorMsg.is(':visible') ){          
        errorMsg.parents('.formResponsive').addClass('something');          
    } 

});
```

Comment: Thank you, that will add a class to the error message though won't it and not the form ?

Comment: @RustyJoomla - Sorry, I've updated the code for you ;)

Comment: Thanks but doesn't appear to be working, I've updated the code above (when the error is shown)

Comment: Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: ReferenceError: error is not defined

if( error.is(':visible') ){

Comment: @RustyJoomla - I've updated my code based on your code. Copy and paste it, and let me know the results